# Is there a way to change the query a report uses in Libreoffice Base or better yet to select the query at the time a report is run?

Tags: database, libreoffice, query, report

I have a standard set of data that I always want out of a report, however it could be based on a query of any of the values.  Is it possible to set it up so I double click on a report and it would let me select the query I want to use. Or if not I could set up a template report, copy it and rename it for the most popular queries then change the query attached to that report.  I'm open to any suggestions, books, tutorials, or better practices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

1. Edit the query.
2. Press the "Form Navigator" button.
3. Right clic on the "QueryName" entry, and select "Properties".
4. In the "Value" field change to the name of the query you want to use. Press enter and close the window and save the report, then close it.

That is it, now open the report with data from the other query.